# How to sum elements in a vector whose index is in a HashSet?

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, hashset

I would like to sum elements in a vector whose index exists in a hashset.

I assume there is a combination of iterator adaptors I could use to achieve this, but can't seem to figure out what to use. I know I could create a function and use a for loop over the vector, but I want to do the calculation inline and store straight into a variable.

An example of the behaviour I would like:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

let v: Vec<u32> = vec![5, 3, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let s: HashSet<u32> = [2, 3, 6].iter().copied().collect();

let actual = v.iter()....
let expected = 12;

assert_eq!(actual, expected);
```

Comment: The duplicates [applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69417692379f315d3ac2f5f5edaa254f).

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster . Even though I know this is a duplicate, could you add your code from the playground as an answer for others to see directly on this question?

Comment: Sorry, but answers cannot be added to closed questions.